# Which WPF Brush to use and how to create it

Tags: wpf, 3d, transform, textures, brush

I have a WPF 3D application (C# .NET 4.0) that has a lot of 3D geometries. Now I need to color these geometries by applying a texture. The source for the texture is one large .PNG file like the following:

[image: Example of resultsfile]

The .PNG file contains repeating sections. One section for each combination of Case, Deviation and Harmonic. Cases have one or more deviations (nDev). Cases also have one or more harmonics (nHarm). So the number of sections is equal to the sum of the nDev * nHarm of each Case.

Each row of pixels within a section maps to exactly one geometry.

[image]

The end-user should be able to select a Case (trough combobox), Deviation (trough slider) and Harmonic (trough slider). This combination leads to a section offset. The basic idea is that this section offset can be used to reposition the "mapping area" over the orignal .png, using a TranslateTransform.

Now the challenge(s) I'm facing. A normal resultsfile contains about:
200 to 400 rows per section
32 to 64 harmonics
up till 250 deviations
20 till 30 cases

In order to get maximum performance, I should use textures that stay within the `RenderCapability.MaxHardwareTextureSize` bounds. So I want to split up the .png per Case (and if necessary per deviation and/or harmonic).

Question: How can I split up the original .png file in multiple brushes? And which brush to use for maximum performance? Should I stick with ImageBrush (since it's static after initial splitting up) or use a BitmapCacheBrush i.e.?

Comment: In case you haven't run into this link yet, it might be useful, there's a list of performance tradeoffs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613553.aspx

Comment: Thx for the link. I had already seen that. That's why I'm thinking of using multiple ImageBrushes. Another solution would be to use one BitmapCacheBrush and refill it. That's what I want to find out trough this question.

Comment: However the question is still valid, we have decided to stop using a .png file and to use a binary formatted file with values. I will translate these values on the fly to an image. Expectations are that this will reduce the overall filesize in such manner that it will fit within the MaxHardwareTextureSize bounds ...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) instead of a WPF Brush.  You can then write any pixels you want without caching anything but the pixel data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That was an approach that I originally took. But soon after taking this rout I got an application hang. I filed this over here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678273/use-writeablebitmap-in-combination-with-viewport3d-compositiontarget-rendering-event-hangs-my-application. As a workaround, I use a BitmapImage, which has a constructor overload, allowing to give an byte array that represent the pixeldata. This works perfectly. Can anyone confirm the bug I've found (and vote for solving please).